# Self-resetting crowbar circuit for over-voltage protection

Tags: mosfet, over-voltage-protection, polyfuse

I'm trying to design an over-voltage protection circuit that doesn't rely on custom chips (the chip shortage has shown the danger of relying on this), so I put together a crowbar circuit like this:

[image: Crowbar]

I used a polyfuse since I don't want to have to physically replace any fuses. The circuit works great and cuts things off when I need it to. However, since it is a polyfuse, some current still trickles through and keeps the thyristor ON. It requires fully turning off the power to make the device work again.

I'd like to come up with something that can self-recover, and I wonder if it's possible given the choice of polyfuse and crowbar.

My first thought was to use a P-MOSFET to try and fully block current to the thyristor if the fuse was engaged, but MOSFETs don't have sharp transitions. As the MOSFET starts to block more current, the fuse will block less, and I never get to a point of having blocked current to the thyristor.

[image: Bad idea]

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can change things to be self-healing?

Comment: The whole point of a crowbar circuit is to blow out the fuse in an overvoltage condition. The thyristor turns on with overvoltage and then 'throws a crowbar' on the fuse. If you want this circuit to be self healing, use something other than a fuse

Comment: @VoltageSpike, the SCR puts a crowbar across the supply, shorting it out and blowing the fuse. 'Throwing a crowbar on the fuse' would do the opposite, putting the crowbar in parallel with the fuse and stopping it blowing.

Comment: I never said throw a crowbar across the fuse

Comment: How about a big 28V Zener in place of all of this?  Or two 14v, three 9v, etc.

Comment: @VoltageSpike But you did. Just re-read your comment.

Comment: Where is the word across? I used the word on, that means in the place of the SCR I don't know how you'd read any different

Comment: @voltagespike  Nobody used the word *across*. I’m just saying that both TonyM and I found your wording somewhat misleading. As far as I know the name of the circuit comes from the analogy of throwing a crowbar across/on the output terminals of a supply. That’s what TonyM pointed out. I guess your use of *throwing on the fuse* was intended to mean shattering it as if with a hammer. Or? In any case, no big deal, really.

Comment: I kind of find that amazing, but that's just me.

Comment: @pfabri, the term comes from third-rail electric railways. In the event of a dangerous situation the lineman could trip the power supply by throwing the crowbar to bridge the third rail to one of the running / return rails.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do this? If you want it to reset itself, put the "detection circuit" in before the fuse so it does not try to turn on if the overvoltage condition is still there. Otherwise you'll get pulsing as long as the overvoltage condition is existing.

Comment: You might be able to get rid of the leakage current by just putting a transistor parallel to your "crowbar" that get's activated at the same time as the crowbar itself.

Comment: Maybe you could design a circuit that sensed the voltage across the polyfuse, and have it activate a time delay before applying a pulse to a transistor across the SCR, bypassing the latching current.

Comment: Your circuit is good, I have done it many times. Change the SCR to a N-Channel MOSFET. You may have to adjust the overvoltage sensing values. What will happen is if you get an overvoltage the MOSFET will start to saturate clamping the voltage, it will not be a sharp knee. As the transient receids the MOSFET will turn off. If it is a major event it will trip the Polyfuse blow the fuse saving your electronics but allow transients up to a limit. The Polyfuse adds resistance in the circuit helping protect the MOSFET. You can also thermally connect the fuse to the MOSFET if you want.

Comment: Careful with your MOSFET choice it will not normally be fully enhanced so it will may warm.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably better ways to protect against momentary overvoltage spikes, such as zeners, MOVs, and TVS devices. A crowbar is more appropriate for a condition where an overvoltage condition may persist for longer than a few milliseconds, or where the voltage may be higher than can be safely handled by semiconductor devices. In those cases, the SCR will safely conduct enough current to open a fuse, which can have very high voltage and interrupting current rating. And most of those cases involve problems that need human intervention to analyze and correct the fault condition before replacing the fuse.

But perhaps the self-resetting protection circuit could be in the form of a [fold-back current limiter](https://www.eeeguide.com/foldback-current-limiting-circuit/), often used in power supplies and amplifiers, that limit the amount of power dissipated by the main series regulation device, typically a MOSFET or BJT. I made a simulation for such a circuit, that shows how the output voltage stays in regulation up to a current where the power dissipated in the transistor exceeds a limit, and then enters current regulating mode.

[image: Foldback Current Limiting]

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of a crowbar is to stay on until the power is fully removed. You clearly don't want that.

If you want overvoltage protection that "auto resets": that's called a voltage regulator. Most integrated voltage regulators have temperature protection, so they'll automatically cycle when they get too hot. That's what you'd want. So I'm not so sure what sort of a problem you're trying to solve that a voltage regulator wouldn't.

Since you may not find an integrated voltage regulator with the exact voltage and current capacities you need, you'd have to roll your own.

As a starting point, let's make a series regulator using M1, D1, Q6,Q7. Q5 is the gate load and is normally sinking some  current.

Since Q2 is thermally bound to M1, it will get hotter as M1 gets hot. Eventually, after about 40-50K of temperature rise, Q2's VT will rise enough to begin turning it off. At that point, Q1 starts to hog current, and Q5's base voltage goes down, turning it off. Now M1's gate is deprived of the current sink, and will rise, switching M1 off.

R3 is used to adjust the thermal tripping point and compensate for mismatches in the differential pair.

To be practical, this circuit would need refinement and component spread and stability analysis in an industry-standard SPICE (LTspice, ngspice, Micro-Cap, etc.).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUeEi0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>